# Проблема с воспроизведением MP3 файла

Tags: c#, аудио

MP3 файл воспроизводится через раз, причем очень влияет если допустим дополнительно на ПК просматриваю фильм через VLC плеер.

```
System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                    player.Open(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "sound.mp3", UriKind.Absolute));
                    player.Play();
```

Есть ли 100% надежный код воспроизведения MP3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандартный MediaPlayer в C#, вроде бы, вообще не поддерживает воспроизведение .MP3 файлов. Только .WAV.
100% способ, разумеется, есть. Лучшее решение - 'это использование сторонней библиотеки **[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)**. Библиотека чрезвычайно функциональна, и пользоваться при этом ей очень просто.

Comment: Благодарю, с этой либой все работает стабильно.

Comment: Ну, разумеется :)